# Silent Push iOS doesn't work after reboot

Tags: java, ios, swift, push-notification, silentpush

From my Java Server, I am sending a silent push in that way:

```
PushNotificationBigPayload payload = PushNotificationBigPayload.complex();

// Le decimos que vamos a mandar un silent push
payload.setContentAvailable(true);
payload.addSound("");
payload.addCustomDictionary(CAMPO_IDEN, String.valueOf(aviso.getId()));
...
payload.addCustomDictionary(CAMPO_TEXTO, aviso.getTextos().get(0).getTexto());
```

At first time, everything works right, I reboot my app and it starts to receive silent pushes while it is in background.

Sadly, after a few reboots, my app stops to catch silent pushes. I don't know what is causing the problem. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Apple docs state

> If your app is suspended or not running, the system wakes up or
>   launches your app and puts it into the background running state before
>   calling the method.

But there is an exception to this. Your App is not woken up by a Silent Push if the user has killed the App manually from the device's App switcher.

Comment: I heard about that. I am sure that app is running in background mode after I rebooted the phone and the I didn't kill it manually.